# Batch File won't run the Java Main class

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, java-8

I know the Java main class to my client is `Client`, so I created a batch file with this inside:

```
@echo off
java Client
pause
```

and I get this error:

> ```
> Error: Could not find or load main class Client
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

The following is the folder and file structure.

[image: Folders and Files]

Comment: On my machine, this code works completely fine... Do you have some other configuration you haven't told us?

Comment: add a `cd` as the opening line - what directory does it say it's running in?

Comment: **1** Your batch file is not in the same folder as class file. **2** Your class file if in the same folder doesn't have main method. Suggest you put in `dir Client.class` in the batch file to check `1`. Suggest you check the timestamp of `Client.class` for `2`

Comment: C:\Users\Zachy\Desktop\Programming Dev\RSPS Server\Client\bin\com\runescape>java Client
Error: Could not find or load main class Client

It appears to be in the proper files. Not sure why it doesn't work, when I run with Eclipse I dont need to add any other parameters, it runs just fine.

Comment: your comment has the answer. your class name is `com.runescape.Client` and not `Client` and also you should run from `bin` directory not from `runescape` directory.

Answer (score 0):

`cd`

> C:\Users\Zachy\Desktop\Programming Dev\RSPS Server\Client\bin\com\runescape>

`cd ..\..\`
`cd`

> C:\Users\Zachy\Desktop\Programming Dev\RSPS Server\Client\bin>

`dir com\runescape\Client.class`

> Client.class ....

`java com.runescape.Client`

This should work now

Comment: `cd`  argh... shouldn't be doing this without access to a dos

Comment: You are using CMD, not DOS.

Comment: @Stevefest ok, windows CMD?

Comment: Yes. Command processor, CMD. DOS is an operating system from the 80s/90s, and I am pretty sure you aren't use that.

Comment: Yes, I use it once in a while and I run it from a 5 quarter inch floppy drive. I've a copy of it in 3 half inch one, just to be safe. Hehe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154023/discussion-between-stevefest-and-bulbus).